# Programming usable and maintainable code

Tags: .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I'm new to reactive programming and came across a problem...

My code is looking like this:

```
    IsBusy = true;
    service.BeginGetClients(param, c => 
    {
        var r = service.EndGetClients(c);
        if(!CheckResult(r))
        {
            service.BeginGetCachedClients(param, c2 =>
                {
                    var r2 = service.EndGetCachedClients(c2);
                    if(CheckResult(r2))
                        ShowMessage("clients valid");
                    else
                        ShowMessage("clients not valid");

                    UpdateClients(r2);

                    service.BeginUpdateClients(r2, c3 =>
                        {
                            var b = service.EndUpdateClients(c3);
                            if(b)
                                ShowMessage("clients updated");
                            else
                                ShowMessage("clients not updated");
                            IsBusy = false;
                        }, null);

                }, null);
        }
        else
        {
            ShowMessage("error on get clients");
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }, null);
```

How can be changed to fluent Rx? I started with this code:

```
    var invokeClients = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<Param, List<Client>>(service.BeginGetClients, service.EndGetClients);
    var invokeCachedClients = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<Param, List<Client>>(service.BeginGetCachedClients, service.EndGetCachedClients);
    invokeClients(param)
    .Subscribe(r =>
    {
        if(!CheckResult(r))
        {
            invokeCachedClients(param)
            .Subscribe(r2 =>
            {
                // TODO: next op
            });
        }
    });
```

Any suggestions improving this code? Maybe another solution?
I don't like this cascading code...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
invokeClients(param)
    .Where(x => !CheckResult(x))
    .Select(invokeCachedClients)
    .Do(_ => IsBusy = true)
    .Merge()
    .Do(_ => IsBusy = false)
    .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Do something here"));
```

Make sure to have that subscribe, or else it won't work (it'd be like not Foreach'ing a LINQ query)

Comment: I would add the IsBusy thing in too.

Answer (score 1):

As per the answer above

```
invokeClients(param)
  .Where(x => !CheckResult(x))
  .SelectMany(invokeCachedClients)
  .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Do something here"));
```

which could also be written as

```
var query = from client in invokeClients(param)
  where !CheckResult(client)
  from cache in invokeCachedClients(client)
  select cache;
```

then you could have the busy flag wrapped in a resource

```
Func<IDisposable> busyResource = 
  () =>
  {
    IsBusy = true;
    return Disposable.Create(() => IsBusy = false);
  };
```

Now you can bring it altogether with the Using factory.

```
Observable.Using(busyResource, _=>query)
  .Subscribe(x=>Console.Write("Do something here");
```

The reason you would favor the Using method instead of putting the IsBusy setters int he OnError or OnCompleted is because this will stop it if the subscription is disposed too.

I am sure we could probably do even better than this, but I am finding it hard to understand what it is you are actually doing. To be honest I think this is actually a better fit for TPL or Data Workflows than Rx, ie you are actually chaining work continuations instead of reacting a sequence of events.

Answer (score 0):

With things like these, you always want to go inside out.  The hardest part about translating this is the parts between the async calls.  If you were feeding the result of one right into the next, it would be a straight forward `from x in async1() from y in async2(x) ...`.  I see two functions that I would break this into:

```
public IObserservable<string> UpdateCachedClients(object param)
{
    var getCachedClientsAsync = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<...>(service.BeginGetCachedClients, service.EndGetCachedClients);
    var updateClientsAsync = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<...>(service.BeginUpdateClients, service.EndUpdateClients);

    return Observable.Create<string>(obs =>
    {
        return (from r2 in getCachedClientsAsync(param)
                            .Do(v => 
                                { if (CheckResult(v))
                                      obs.OnNext("clients valid");
                                  else
                                      obs.OnNext("clients not valid");
                                  //huh? is this done twice
                                  UpdateClients(v); 
                                })
                from b in updateClientsAsync(r2)
                select (b ? "clients updated" : "clients not updated")
               ).Subscribe(obs);
    });
}

public IObservable<string> UpdateAllClients(object param)
{
    var getClientsAsync = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<...>(service.BeginGetClients, service.EndGetClients);
    return from r in getClientsAsync(param)
           select (CheckResult(r) ? 
                     Observable.Return("error on get clients") :
                     UpdateCachedClients(param));
}
```

I used an extra layer of `Observable.Create` in the first function because it seemed the simplest way to pass a result out and continue with the next call.  Once you have these two functions, you should be able to call them like:

```
IsBusy = true;
var disp = UpdateAllClients(param)
            .Subscribe(ShowMessage,
                       ex => IsBusy = false,
                       () => IsBusy = false);
```

Note that I've set `IsBusy` to false in both the OnError and OnCompleted, since either is a terminating message for IObservable.

The TPL seems a more natural fit for async methods like this as they only produce one value, but until the next version of the languages with async/await, you will probably end up with similar syntax to either your method or mine if you use Tasks instead of IObservables.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot. But how to abort the first op?
"from b in updateClientsAsync(r2)" should not be called.
What would you prefer in the future: async/await methods or Rx?